# Targeting more than one element with jQuery hover

Tags: jquery, hover, block

I have multiple divs called image-wrap, and when I hover on one of them, I want to show the elements inside that specific image-wrap, in this case, the link and image inside the p tag called item (instead of showing all of them). I've searched the net and most answers I found said to use $(this). I don't want to affect the image-wrap, so $(this) wouldn't work.

The html:

```
<div class="image-wrap">
<p class="item"><span><a href="#">Link</a><img src=" "></span></p>
</div>

<div class="image-wrap">
<p class="item"><span><a href="#">Link</a><img src=" "></span></p>
</div>

<div class="image-wrap">
<p class="item"><span><a href="#">Link</a><img src=" "></span></p>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
<script>
$('.image-wrap').hover( 
function() {
$('.item').css('display','block');
},
function() {
$('.item').css('display','none');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this particular problem is to use CSS, not javascript.
Please consider the following CSS instead:

```
.image-wrap .item {
  display: none;
}

.image-wrap:hover .item {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('.image-wrap').hover( 
function() {
$('.item',this).css('display','block');
},
function() {
$('.item',this).css('display','none');
});
```

it will find the `.item` in the specific `.image-wrap`

Comment: Instead of modifying CSS directly, `show` and `hide` could have been used

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
$('.image-wrap').hover( 
function() {
  $(this).children('.item').css('display','block');
},
function() {
  $(this).children('.item').css('display','none');
});
```

or

```
$('.image-wrap').hover( 
function() {
  $(this).children('.item').show();
},
function() {
  $(this).children('.item').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it most definitely works. I'm wondering what's the difference between show/hide vs display block/none?

Comment: @tickerll please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562439/difference-between-jquery-hide-css-display-none

Answer (score 0):

> *"I don't want to affect the image-wrap, so $(this) wouldn't work."*

You *do* need to use `$(this)` - the idea is to start from `$(this)` and use DOM [traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to select the related elements. In your case `$(this).children()` should do the trick, or `$(this).find('.item')`:

```
$('.image-wrap').hover( 
function() {
   $(this).children().show();
},
function() {
   $(this).children().hide();
});
```

Also there's no need to mess around setting the CSS properties directly when jQuery provides [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KsqaW/

(Note that you need other content in your divs that isn't hidden or there's nothing to hover over.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info about DOM. I've just started javascript and DOM is still not completely clear to me. Your explanation just opened my eyes!

Comment: You're welcome. DOM traversal is reasonably easy with jQuery, because jQuery provides all sorts of methods for navigating up or down (to ancestors and descendants) or sideways (to siblings).

Comment: I just thought of something...what if the item wasn't inside the div tag and was elsewhere?