# jQuery show() and hide() vs classes with display:block / none

Tags: jquery, css

Just out of curiosity, which of these two techniques is more "valid" to use?

I had a discussion with my supervisor and he told me that I should create two classes with display:block/none and assign them to elements using jQuery, rather than using jQuery's own functions show/hide.

I had the impression that show/hide are widely used functions that work without any issues and they were made to make our lives easier by not forcing us to assign classes.

Comment: They work just fine. It may be a matter of coding standards where you work.

Comment: Are exactly the same ... of course if you're using jquery prefer show and hide instead of making classes ... Only about show and hide is that makes inlin styles

Comment: View the differences here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562439/difference-between-jquery-hide-and-cssdisplay-none

Comment: Ih the end jquery show/hide adds an inline style with display:block/none

Comment: Though this an interesting subject, it is primarily opinion-based, and as such I'm afraid doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. At the end of the day, choosing between either is neither more "valid" nor more "proper". It depends on circumstance more than anything else.

Comment: That's my point. They are both the same, but my supervisor thinks that using class is more "valid" than adding an inline-style to an element.

Comment: @Peter Using classes is the exact opposite of inline style. Your supervisor's approach is misguided.

Comment: From a validity point of view they effectively equate, albeit with one minor difference, so are equally valid (see link posted by DSG). jQuery arguably more so as it restores the elements previous/default display setting, instead of setting it to show outright

Comment: Using CSS classes isn't more valid. If you're going to use jQuery, why not make use of its many helpful functions, including `show()` and `hide()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such CSS classes to initially hide element on the page to show it later with `jQuery.show()`.
Anyway `jQuery.show()` sets the style property directly so the browser don't need to lookup through CSS declaration to find a class each time you assign it. So I believe it will work faster and also is more convenient to developer. By the way the code with `show/hide` is also more readable.

Just compare

```
$username.hide();
```

to

```
$username.addClass('hidden');
```

Seems the code is more readable, so that it's more maintainable, therefore it's cheaper for customer to support it... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same - `show()` and `hide()` just switches between `display: block` (or `inline`, `inline-block`, etc) and `display: none` or similar.  Using these or using simple classes to switch between those styles are both perfectly "valid".

The main difference is that `show()` and `hide()` support jQuery animations out of the box.  Also, classes do not add inline CSS, whereas `show()` and `hide()` do (inline html to override whatever the initial `display` value is).  Depending on your use case this may or may not be convenient.

`show()` and `hide()` also cache the initial `display` value so if you `hide()` an element and then `show()` it, it will remember what the original `display` value was (which means it's more flexible since you don't need unique visible classes for elements with different types of `display` values).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "invalid" about using either of the two techniques. It boils down to your preference I believe. jQuery's show/hide methods work perfectly well. Some points to consider

- If you use show/hide, it's a pure javascript/jquery based solution.
- If you use CSS classes by assigning them USING jquery this method involves CSS + jquery

Having said that it's always recommended to use a CSS solution wherever possible. If you create classes with display block/none like you said, you can use them throughout your application. So I guess in the end it's up to ypur personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference in the approaches is that by doing it with classes you can chose how you hide in future re-stylings.  You might want to swap in a new CSS one day where hidden is actually crossed through and grayed out.  By using classes you maintain a separation of presentation and data.