# How to hide the div and place coverd by div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#visualization").hide();
    $("#visualization1").hide();
});
```

HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" ></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="visualization1" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this code i can hide the div but,it shows the div space and it try to adjust the other content(in the page) into that space.Can anyone help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:none`

like: `jQuery('#id').css("display","none");`

```
$("#visualization").css('display','none');
```

please have a read [Difference between jQuery .hide() and .css("display", "none")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562439/difference-between-jquery-hide-and-cssdisplay-none) too..!!

**OR**

```
document.getElementbyId("visualization").style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hiding it, you can set the `visibility` state of your div to `hidden` using **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**:

```
$("#visualization").css('visibility','hidden');
```

From the **[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)**:

> The hidden value of visibility property will hides an element but leaves space where it would have been.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `visibility:hidden` like

```
$("#visualization").css('visibility','hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

```
$("#visualization, #visualization1").css('visibility','hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `visibility` property to `hidden`:

```
 document.getElementById("visualization").style.visibility="hidden";
 document.getElementById("visualization1").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xU9Su/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

This will Replace the place but in case of visibility : hidden content will be in hidden mode but that occupied place remain a blank space on there

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
                     $("#visualization").css('display','none');
              $("#visualization1").css('display','none');

     });

</script>
```